# Do ability-boosting items or spells count for meeting feat prerequisites?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, feat-qualifications, bonus-type

Do ability-boosting items or spells count for meeting feat prerequisites? I always reckoned that they do not. But now I wonder.

For example, the text for Gloves of Dexterity is

> They add to the wearer's Dexterity score in the form of an enhancement
>   bonus

So it comes down to the question: does a bonus become part of the score itself? This seems logical in the case of an inherent bonus. The inherent bonus is just a means of keeping track of permanent magical boosting e.g. via wish spells. This kind of boost is limited to 5 points. As a DM I would judge that boosting an ability score via wish spells does count for meeting prerequisites for feats. But, if so: What is the difference to an enhancement bonus?

Ok, it may not be permanent. But there are rules what happens if you no longer meet prerequisites: the feat ceases functioning until you meet the prerequisites again.

This kind of ruling would even mean you could cast a boost spell before leveling up to meet prerequisites, take a feat and this feat only works while you have enough active boosts.

So my question: Do ability boosting items or spells count for meeting prerequisites for feats?

Comment: This question is answered for magic items [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23119/8610) and for spells [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110627/8610). I'm not sure I can mark this a duplicate of both. Do you want to revise the question?

Comment: Ok, I did not see those! I delete! Best regards

Comment: Last question: does this also apply to prestige classes?

Comment: Since the answer to this question in both cases is *yes*, figuring out why the same rules would *not* apply to prestige class requirements would be the first step in formulating a new question.

Comment: Ok, I consider that AFTER some research. Sorry for not deleting, but I did not find the delete function in the handy  app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could take the feat, but you would lose the use of the feat if, for whatever reason, you lose the bonus from the item.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You can improve this answer by quoting/citing rules to support your answer. Take the [tour] if you haven't already and check out the [help] center if you need more guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Thanks for answering - but my question had already been asked, I am just late deleting it. Best regards Giorin

Comment: Thank you for answering. You are right But I have been made aware of this question being a duplicate.

Comment: @Giorin No problem.